# Webmethods - Retrieve PDF file from SFTP and encode

Tags: pdf, encoding, sftp, webmethods

I am new to webmethods and need some guidance. I am tasked to read the PDF document from SFTP server and base64 encode it. I have managed to GET the file from SFTP location and now struggling to encode it. Below is the code snippet to read the file:

```
INVOKE pub.client.sftp:login
INVOKE pub.client.sftp:cd
INVOKE pub.client.sftp:ls
INVOKE pub.client.sftp:get
MAP
```

I later modified the code to include base64 encoding, no output is produced. Code is shown below:

```
INVOKE pub.client.sftp:login
INVOKE pub.client.sftp:cd
INVOKE pub.client.sftp:ls
INVOKE pub.client.sftp:get
INVOKE pub.string:base64Encode
MAP
```

when i debug the code, it executes SFTP GET and stops. No information about encoding.

[image]

[image]

Please guide me to achieve this requirement. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,
[image: Sequence]
after sftp:get, invoke the **pub.io:streamToBytes** and then invoke **pub.string:base64Encode**

Don't forget to map field in pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The pub.string:base64Encode expect a byte[] Input, you can try to convert the stream to byte[] with pub.io:streamToBytes

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried using pub.io:streamToBytes and get below error: com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException: [ISS.0086.9167] stream is a required field

Comment: Did you map the output of sftp.get to the input of streamToBytes as shown in alexringo Answer?